# JSP : Different view result MVC1 and MVC2 in my project. Why is it?

Tags: java, jsp, ibatis

I made a some page using MVC2. But it can't display all data that model component called.

So I try to make page using MVC1. It worked.

I wonder why 2 pages are different. Why It is?

// This is the view - MVC1(bottom in photo - AdminMemberList.jsp), MVC(top in photo - AdminMemberList.do)

[image]

// This is the result of model output data(in console) - same MVC1 and MVC2

```
Member [id=aaaa, point=50, birthday=1923-01-01, email=dwd@google.com]
Member [id=admin, point=40, birthday=1999-01-03, email=ks@nad.com]
Member [id=bbbb, point=20, birthday=1454-09-03, email=bbb]
Member [id=bbbbbb, point=10, birthday=1970-01-01, email=bb@bd.com]
Member [id=david, point=10, birthday=1990-12-30, email=dkakd@gmd.com]
Member [id=davidhong, point=10, birthday=1967-03-09, email=hong@dsd.com]
Member [id=happy, point=30, birthday=1983-03-02, email=gg@gg.com]
Member [id=imyourman, point=10, birthday=1978-02-02, email=kakd@ddl.com]
Member [id=kaaf, point=10, birthday=1978-07-03, email=akd@em]
Member [id=solomon, point=10, birthday=1989-09-12, email=solomon@gmail.com]
Member [id=sunny, point=10, birthday=1985-04-02,email=akdfjl@em.com]
Member [id=xxxxxx, point=10, birthday=1982-01-01, email=del@do.com]
```

//   AdminMemberList.jsp - This is view component : MVC1 & MVC2 same

```
<body style="padding-top: 55px;">

    <jsp:include page="ConnectDB.jsp"/>
    <jsp:include page="CommonTopmenu.jsp" flush="false"/>

    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row">
            <div>
            <!-- <div id="main" class="col-sm-9 col-sm-offset-3 col-md-10 col-md-offset-2 main">-->
                <h4>Member Info</h4>
                <button type="button" id="ajaxDeleteMemberData" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary">Remove</button>
                <button type="button" id="ajaxUpdateMemberData" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary">Update</button>
                <span>Total : ${countMember} people</span>
                <table class="table table-hover" id="tabletest">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th><input type="checkbox" id="changeChecking" name="changeChecking"></th>
                            <th>ID</th> <th>Point</th>
                            <th>Birthday</th> <th>Email</th> <th>Regdate</th> <th>Password</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <c:forEach items="${articleList}" var="article">
                    <tbody>                 
                        <tr>
                            <td><input type="checkbox" class="tr_check" name="check2"></td>
                            <td>${article.id}</td>
                            <td ><input type="number" class="point" name="${article.id}" min="0" max="300" step="10"
                                        value="${article.point}"/></td>
                            <td>${article.birthday}</td>
                            <td>${article.email}</td>
                            <td>${article.regdate}</td>
                            <td><input type="text" name="${article.id}" value="${article.password}"/>
                                <input type="button" class="btnChange" name="${article.id}" value="Edit">
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                    </c:forEach>
                </table>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

// AdminMemberListAction.do - This is the model component : ***MVC2***

```
public class AdminMemberListAction implements CommandAction {

    @Override
    public String requestPro(HttpServletRequest request,
            HttpServletResponse response) throws Throwable {

            List<Board> list = null;
            int countMember =0;
            String res="orm/mybatis/config.xml";
            try{
                InputStream is = Resources.getResourceAsStream(res);
                SqlSessionFactory factory = new SqlSessionFactoryBuilder().build(is);
                SqlSession sqlSession = factory.openSession();

                list = sqlSession.selectList("getMemberList");
                sqlSession.close();            
            }catch(IOException ie){
                System.out.println(ie.getMessage());
            }
            countMember = list.size();

            for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
                System.out.println(list.get(i));
            }

            request.setAttribute("articleList", list); 
            request.setAttribute("countMember", countMember);

        return "AdminMemberList.jsp";
        }
 }
```

// ConnectDB.jsp - This is the model component : ***MVC1***

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"
    pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
    <%@ page import="java.sql.*" %>
    <%@ page import="java.util.*" %>
<%
    try {
        String driverName = "org.mariadb.jdbc.Driver";  
        String url = "jdbc:mariadb://localhost:3306/team";  
        ResultSet rs = null;

        Class.forName(driverName);
        Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(url,"id","password");       
        Statement stmt = con.createStatement();         
        String sql = "SELECT * from member";
        rs = stmt.executeQuery(sql);

        ArrayList<HashMap<String, Object>> list = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, Object>>();
        HashMap<String, Object> hm = new HashMap<String, Object>();

        while(rs.next()){
            hm = new HashMap<String, Object>();
            hm.put("id", rs.getString("id"));
            hm.put("point", rs.getString("point"));
            hm.put("birthday", rs.getString("birthday"));
            hm.put("email", rs.getString("email"));
            list.add(hm);
        }

        request.setAttribute("articleList", list);
        con.close();
    }catch (Exception e) {
        out.println("Oracle Database Connection Something Problem. <hr>");
        out.println(e.getMessage());
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
%>
```

Comment: Can you show your `/config.xml` , i guess you are querying different tables

Comment: //This is my /config.xml `<environment id="development">
            <transactionManager type="JDBC" />
            <dataSource type="POOLED">
                <property name="driver" value="org.mariadb.jdbc.Driver" />
                <property name="url" value="jdbc:mariadb://localhost:3306/team" />
                <property name="username" value="id" />
                <property name="password" value="password" />
            </dataSource>
        </environment>`

Comment: //This is my qeury in mybatis `<select id="getMemberList" resultType="com.board.beans.Member">
      SELECT * from member
 </select>`

Comment: @SanKrish I can get the same data on console, but it can't make same view. I wonder this.